Redirect to a different port in IIS
I have a site in IIS which I also connected to a domain, say our domain name is x.net
And the site port is 8044
x.net:8044 is working fine from a public IP address, however what I'd like to do is when typing x.net from public, I want to redirect it to x.net:8044. I've tried all kinds of AI tools and they all responded with the URL rewrite, I've done almost all of them with no luck. What am I missing?

What port were you using before?

Maybe you want a proxy instead of a redirect. With a redirect, you go to example.com, and the browser forwards you to example.com:8044. With a proxy, you go to example.com and display the info on port 8044 (while still showing example.com in the address bar to the user)

I think what you are looking at is to implement port redirection in your router.  Any decent router will have such a facility.  You need to redirect port 80 to port 8044.
